# Saving different types of objects

Tags: java, save, serializable

I'm not really sure how else I can state the title but here goes:

I have multiple classes:

```
DamageType
Proficiencies
Race
```

These all need to be saved into .ser files. I thought I'd save time by creating a singular method for all 3 so I needed a saving method that parsed all these objects. I had the classes implement `Serializable` so that I could create the following method:

```
createFile(Serializable object){
    File file = new File("./src/"+object+".ser");
    file.createNewFile();
    fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    oos.writeObject(object);
}
```

However, when retrieving the object from the file, it returns as a `Serializable` interface and I'm unable to convert that interface into a class.

```
public static ArrayList<Serializable> readFolder(File folder, ArrayList<String> exceptions) {
    ArrayList<Serializable> objects = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
    for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (!(exceptions.contains(fileEntry.getName()))) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                readFolder(fileEntry, exceptions);
            } else {
                objects.add(fileEntry);
            }
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

How else can I do it? Do I have to bite the bullet and just create a `createFile` method for each one?

Comment: I dont see where you are retrieving object from the file in your `createFile` method.

Comment: @tsolakp I'll update the post with the code for retrieving

Comment: Do you know what will be the expected type of each deserialized class?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but all the classes are in separate folders. Thus, the ArrayList<Seriablizable> should only contain a single class.

Comment: So, under a particular folder you will only have serialized files for objects of type `DamageType` and under different folder only for `Proficiencies`?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: BTW, in your `readFolder` you are adding `File` object to `objects` and not the actually deserialized object.

Comment: You're right, I am. I didn't notice that; I'll go fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is generic `readFolder` that reads Objects assuming that there is of same given type of serialized objects under a given folder/file and does not traverse sub-folders.

```
public static <T extends Serializable> List<T> readFolder(Class<T> clazz, File file, List<String> exceptions){
    File[] files = file.isDirectory() ? file.listFiles() : new File[]{file};

    List<T> objects = new ArrayList<T>();

    for ( File f : files ){
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( new FileInputStream(f) ) ) {
            T object = clazz.cast( ois.readObject() );
            objects.add(object);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exceptions.add( e.getMessage() );  
        }
    }        
    return objects;
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
List<DamageType> dts = readFolder( DamageType.class, new File(""), new ArrayList<>() );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have an abstract classe like form example "SerFile" where has the implementation of createFile method. Each class should extend that abstract class.

Comment: Some of the classes that I need to save are extending other abstract classes.

Comment: Ok, maybe I would need the hole picture to give the best solution. You could also save the class in another format, for example json. And then when reading it you could map to the specific class.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with json. Is there any articles you can guide me to about how to use it, especially in this context?

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: Thank you! I think this will be very useful.